# Why do I keep getting the same val_accuracy in text classification with lstm?

Tags: python, keras, text, lstm, tf-idf

I am trying to classify korean_text with LSTM.

but i am getting the same val_accuracy, i don`t know where the problem is...

```
Epoch 1/500
213/213 [==============================] - 176s 798ms/step - loss: 3.7828 - acc: 0.1954 - val_loss: 3.6719 - val_acc: 0.2125
Epoch 2/500
213/213 [==============================] - 170s 798ms/step - loss: 3.7118 - acc: 0.1999 - val_loss: 3.6587 - val_acc: 0.2125
Epoch 3/500
213/213 [==============================] - 170s 797ms/step - loss: 3.7076 - acc: 0.1999 - val_loss: 3.6618 - val_acc: 0.2125
Epoch 4/500
213/213 [==============================] - 169s 795ms/step - loss: 3.7053 - acc: 0.1999 - val_loss: 3.6617 - val_acc: 0.2125
Epoch 5/500
213/213 [==============================] - 170s 798ms/step - loss: 3.7045 - acc: 0.1999 - val_loss: 3.6591 - val_acc: 0.2125
Epoch 6/500
213/213 [==============================] - 170s 799ms/step - loss: 3.7029 - acc: 0.1999 - val_loss: 3.6654 - val_acc: 0.2125
Epoch 7/500
213/213 [==============================] - 170s 800ms/step - loss: 3.7034 - acc: 0.1999 - val_loss: 3.6572 - val_acc: 0.2125
```

using tf-idf vectorizer, LSTM layer.

here my code.

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5)
tfidf_vectorizer.fit(train_df.overview)
# tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(train_df.overview.tolist()).toarray()
X_test_tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(test_df.overview.tolist()).toarray()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(X_train_tfidf.shape[1], 120)) 
# model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.8))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=30, verbose=1)

history = model.fit(X_train_tfidf, train_df.cat3.values, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True,  batch_size=64, epochs=500, callbacks=[es])
```

and train, test data shape is..

```
X_train_tfidf.shape, X_test_tfidf.shape
>>> ((16986, 14256), (7280, 14256))
```

Can anyone tell me where the problem is?